# Remove-AzAutomationSchedule needs confirmation, even with confirm parameter

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I got a code collecting and deleting expired azure automation schedules

```
Connect-AzAccount -SubscriptionId "guidstuff"
$schedules = Get-AzAutomationSchedule -ResourceGroupName "resgrp" -AutomationAccountName "automationacc" | ?{$_.name -like "schedule1*" -and $_.expirytime -lt (get-date)}
$cache = Get-AzAutomationSchedule -ResourceGroupName "resgrp" -AutomationAccountName "automationacc" | ?{$_.name -like "schedule2*" -and $_.expirytime -lt (get-date)}
if($cache.count -ne 0){
    $schedules += $cache
}
foreach($schedule in $schedules){
    Remove-AzAutomationSchedule -Confirm:$false -AutomationAccountName $schedule.AutomationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $schedule.ResourceGroupName -Name $schedule.name 
}
```

Its asking deletion-confirmation for every schedule, am I or is the CMDlet wrong ?

Comment: Can you try adding switch `-Force` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its asking deletion-confirmation for every schedule, am I or is the CMDlet wrong ?

As suggested by @theo, we reproduced in our local environment by using the below cmdlet:

By default, `-Confirm` value is set to false only.

```
Remove-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName 'tstautmation'-ResourceGroupName 'test-rg' -Name 'terer' -Confirm:$false -Force
```

Now, it will not ask for deletion-confirmation every time when we run the above command.

Refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/remove-azautomationschedule?view=azps-8.1.0) for more information.

Comment: thanks, adding -force did it.